# Random-effects anova

Tags: r, anova, lme4-nlme

I have a continuous dependent variable $y$ and two independent categorical variables $x_1$ and $x_2$.  As well, they have been sampled from different sites (site).

$x_1$ has 3 levels
$x_2$ has 5 levels

is it correct to do:

```
dat <- aov(y ~ x1*x2 + Error(site))
```

or

```
dat <- lme(y ~ x1*x2, random  = ~1 | site, data=data, na.action=na.omit)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: How many sites?

Comment: There are many possible models. The choice depends on the nature of your real problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since X1 and X2 are categorical, so you should use `factor()`

`lme1 <- lme(y ~ factor(x1)*factor(x2), random  = ~1 | site, data=data, na.action=na.omit)`

and then use `anova()` to do ANOVA.

`anova(lme1)`

But you should notice the attribute of `type` in `anova.lme()`, choosing 'marginal' or 'sequential' ANOVA based on your need.